# Publisher - Subscriber communication between un-related components in Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, publish-subscribe

I am using Angular4 app with typescript. I have a left menu (component 1), clicking on one of the items loads a screen (component 2).

On the action of button click in component2 I want component 1 to load menu items.

I tried Observable.Subscribe() & Subject.next() with a shared service. However this does not work.

I also tried this http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject with no help at all.

Can someone please help me understand/direct me in the right direction for me to achieve this.

Comment: Create a shared service that will hold the value/s you'd like each component to access.

Comment: thanks, if it was meant to load when the component loads, that is fine, however, I want component 1 subscribed code to run on no event on component 1 and on event action on component 2.

Do you have an example, as I have implemented a shared service as i suggested in the question.